# Laravel Lumen eloquent left join returns joined table data rather than primary able data

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, lumen, lumen-8

I have two tables company and courses table
The table has the following fields

```
 companies table
  id, full_name, email, deleted_at
```

and courses table

```
 courses table
  id, company_id, course_name,deleted_at
```

Now i would like to retrieve all courses which company is not deleted. So in my controller i have added

```
public function index(Request $request){

  $query = Courses::query();
  $query = $query->leftJoin('companies','companies.id','=','courses.company_id');
  $query->whereNull('companies.deleted_at');
  if($request->get('filter_name')){
    $query = $query->where('courses.name', 'like', '%' . $request->get('filter_name') . '%');
  }
 
  return  response()->json($query->paginate($request->get("perPage")));  
}
```

When i run the above it returns companies data rather than courses. Where am i going wrong or what am i missing out?

Comment: Its still giving me this issue also. Am using laravel lumen for this.

Comment: $query = Courses::query();
        $query->leftJoin('companies','companies.id','=','courses.company_id');
        $query->whereNull('companies.deleted_at');
        if($request->get('filter_name')){
            $query->where('courses.name', 'like', '%' . $request->get('filter_name') . '%');
        }   is ithis query you tried.in previous comment i had other query so

Comment: Yes its this one and still getting the same issue.

Comment: You want this `'Now i would like to retrieve all courses which company is not deleted'`. Rewrite the query `$query->whereNull('companies.deleted_at');` to `$query->whereNotNull('companies.deleted_at');`

Answer (score 0):

If you have use eager loading in both of your model, you can use this kind of approach.

```
$all_course = Courses::with(['company', function($query) {
                            return $query->whereNotNull('deleted_at');
                       }])->get();
```

As you can see, I query in the Courses model to return all the courses but I added some filter in the `company` relationship. where in I used `whereNotNull` to get only the company that's not deleted.